# Google play list this error Broadcast of Intent { act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED

Tags: flutter

I got following error on google play store but I have no idea why this error occured. They said that it is happing on (Sharp AQUOS sense2 SH-01L Android 9 (SDK 28) ).
I have logcat but I can't find anything in logcat too. I already released to production. This one is my bugs fixed for new release.

```
ANR in com.google.android.apps.tachyon;PID: 18069;Broadcast of Intent { 
act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 cmp=com.google.android.apps.tachyon/com.google.apps.tiktok.account.data.device.DeviceAccountsChangedReceiver_Receiver };
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I had the same error this morning in my latest app version's pre-launch report. It too was with a Sharp AQUOS sense2 SH-01L Android 9 (SDK 28) device. According to the video, firebase was tapping away on a non-selectable ListView when it occurred, so I don't see how that would trigger this error.

Answer (score 6):

A similar Error occurred for me as well.
"ANR in com.google.android.apps.tachyon" at same device "Sharp AQUOS sense2 SH-01L"

```
 E/ActivityManager(1566): ANR in com.google.android.apps.tachyon
 E/ActivityManager(1566): PID: 18457
 E/ActivityManager(1566): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED flg=0x11200010 cmp=com.google.android.apps.tachyon/.common.applifecycle.LocaleChangeReceiver }
```

I believe this device has com.google.android.apps.tachyon app is installed by default and an automatic update for this app could be running in the background (just a guess) which crashes anytime.

The crash is just a coincidence.

It will not happen every time with the same app and with the same use case. It will also not happen with any other device. **just update the versionCode and publish the App again.**

**One other option is to go to the device catalog and mark this device as not supported.**

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I think I have finally solved this for my app.

In my case, other than my main activity, the other Activies were only called by my app. In my activities in my AndroidManifest.xml, I had

```
android:exported="true"
```

Of course, this allows these activities to be invoked by other external activities/etc

By changing this to:

```
android:exported="false"
```

...it prevents the activity from being called.

In my case and going through the logs, I didn't see anything that jumped out and bit me but my research led me to believe that com.google.apps.tiktok.* was some sort of old transactional piece of Android. Also, I noticed my Tutorial activity was logging well after it should have been.

My suspicion is the test may actually be real and intended to check for either Activities handling external launches or checking for a security injection of some kind.

I think the use case is likely that an Android user is changed on the phone (usually at end of these robo tests), ticktok handles that and sends this intent/message to all externally known Activities. If so, that would mean either the Activities have to not be exported or handle the intent appropriately.

Anyhow, this change helped me tremendously and I haven't hit this with this app since after about 100 robo tests. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with Google Play Store testing devices. Problems went away without me making any changes on a new release.

Comment: Yes. it is. I just leave it as it is.